# how to link css to base template using Jinja 2?

Tags: html, css, jinja2

I am using Jinja 2 to build my website and in my main template I have something such as this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
```

and every time I run it, it says that 
`url_for is undefiend` 
If anyone could point me in the right direction I will appreciate it a lot! 
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are using Jinja. Look at some examples. Anyway, I just do the below, as it doesn't use Jinja.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/css/main.css">
```